# ADB: Device could not be created

Tags: android, windows, xamarin, android-device-manager

I setted up my **Visual Studio 2017** to start developing **Xamarin - Android** apps, already installed **Android 8.1 Oreo(API lvl. 27)** and **Android 8.0 Oreo(API lvl. 26)** and some platform tools.

Have `JAVA_HOME` pointing to **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221** and `ANDROID_HOME` to **C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk**.

[image]
[image]

I launch **Visual Studio** by **administrator**, but also tried **launched ADB from cmd with administratior mode**.
When I try to create new virtual device with **Android Device Manager** launched from Visual Studio: Tools>Android>Android Device Manager..., the following message shown:

> Device could not be created
>
> Please run repair on the device, and report the issue if the problem
>   persists.  Please file an issue by choosing "Report a Problem" in the
>   Help menu, and attach your logs.  Error summary: avdmanager has
>   returned non-zero exit code: {0}. Please check logs for more
>   information.

I checked the logs at "C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Roaming\XamarinDeviceManager" and it starts with this:

```
[19-07-21 15:48:30.07] Android Device Manager version 1.0.624.20 (1.0.624.20+7361af75d162a09d91b3af3b287c187c805161d1)
[19-07-21 15:48:30.08] Operating system: Windows 10 v10.0.17134 (Windows 10 Pro; Microsoft Windows 10 v10.0.17134 (Windows 10 Pro; 64-bit)), 64-bit
[19-07-21 15:48:30.15] [AppInfo] Detected Android SDK path: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk
[19-07-21 15:48:30.25] [ConfigManager] Config file path: <USER_HOME>\AppData\Local\Xamarin\AndroidDevices.exe_Url_xc3zboekagxckk4zetm2vqdih4yy0yl2\1.0.624.20\user.config
[19-07-21 15:48:30.26] [AppInfo] Set ANDROID_SDK_ROOT: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk
[19-07-21 15:48:30.45] --- Device Manager started
[19-07-21 15:48:31.00] [ASDKErrorLogger.BeginStep]: Updating SDK component information…
[19-07-21 15:48:31.00] No Android SDK instance matching the 'C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk' path
[19-07-21 15:48:32.03] Xamarin manifest base URL: https://dl.xamarin.com/Manifest/d15-8/
....
```

I've tried a lot of things already, what could be the solution?

[image]

[image]

Comment: `...Please check logs for more information...` And the log contains what errors?

Comment: edit my question with beginning of logs.

Comment: Try manually creating an AVD using `avdmanager` or use Android Studio's AVD Manager (it is far superior to Xamarin's and I exclusively use it instead Xamarin's Android Device Manager, you can still use the Xamarin one to start the AVD once created, but for the creation part try Android Studio instead to see if it solves the problem...?)

Comment: Thanks, launching AVD from Android Studio solved my problem. Take your commet as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I eliminated that x86 directory and its contents. Then in the project I went to Tools -> Android -> Android Device manager. it brought up the device manager dialog. I clicked add new, It displayed the emulated base image with its parameters. I changed the height and eliminated functions that I would not be using, and clicked create. It showed "unzipping" and eventually returned the message System Image download error. The x86 directory is back.