# Xamarin - Error on creating emulator not working

Tags: windows, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

I downloaded Xamarin to start learning some app development. When I go to create a android emulator, it finishes downloading but I keep getting this error when it reaches 100% on the download:

```
Device could not be created. Please file an issue by choosing "Report a Problem" in the Help menu, and attach your logs. 
Error summary: avdmanager has returned non-zero exit code: -2147467259. Please check logs for more information.
```

I've attached a screenshot as well. I tried searching for any similar errors but no luck. Any recommendations would be appreciated.
Using:
VisualStudio 2019, Win 10 Student, Hyper-V enabled, Intel i7 8th gen w/ 16gb ram
[image: error]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57134790/adb-device-could-not-be-created

Comment: Do you have other other versions of JAVA SDK in your comptuer? If so, uninstall JAVA SDK except SDK 8. Do you have install Android Studio in your computer? If so you can open ADM and create a emulator in AS, Then run it in VS, if you can got the correct result.